# Can't update the system

Tags: release-loki, updates, pantheon-terminal

So, the system is telling me that important updates were found, but every time I run sudo apt update I get these errors.

```
 Err:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kernel-ppa/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release

  404  Not Found
Reading package lists... Done

W: https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main/dists/xenial/InRelease : Signature by key 09D6EF97BFB38E916EF060E756A3DEF863961D39 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/kernel-ppa/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried everything but couldn't find a solution, help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have added this PPA manually. The error says that this software source has no build for Xenial. You should remove this PPA again. Alternative PPA (but is not recommended and supported by elementary's support) would be the [PPA from Canonical Kernel Team](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

Comment: Thanks! What about this one? 

W: https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main/dists/xenial/InRelease : Signature by key 09D6EF97BFB38E916EF060E756A3DEF863961D39 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)

Comment: If you don't know why you want to use this repository, remove it, too. Though, this is only a warning about security. Functionality should not be limited...